# Bioconda: simulate-travis.py fails because api cannot be imported from conda_build

Tags: python, conda, snakemake

I'm struggling to make Bioconda's simulate-travis.py work for a new package and my Google Fu is failing me:

```
./simulate-travis.py --packages verifybamid --loglevel=debug


File "/apps/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/bioconda_utils/utils.py", line 22, in <module>
    from conda_build import api
ImportError: cannot import name 'api'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./simulate-travis.py", line 150, in <module>
    sp.run(['scripts/travis-run.sh'], env=env, universal_newlines=True, check=True)
  File "/apps/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 708, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['scripts/travis-run.sh']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

bioconda-utils itself is failing for the same reason.

The conda_build version is:

```
python -c 'import conda_build; print(conda_build.__version__)'
1.20.3
```

The bioconda-utils version is 0.9.0 (installed via pip).

Is this a simple version mismatch?

Thanks,
Andreas

PS: Couldn't create bioconda tag due to lack of points

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question: It was a version mismatch between conda-build and bioconda-utils. The 'Developer notes' section on https://github.com/bioconda/bioconda-utils describes how to fix it. Either follow instructions there or fix the conda-build version is set in   bioconda-utils.